# Jumpy Emacs cursor movement when going forward

Tags: emacs

When I run Emacs (v23.1.1) in the terminal (without opening a window through X-forwarding) currently, I can't get the cursor to move forward for more than a few positions without it jumping around.

I'm in Windows 10 logging into a server via SSH. I typically work in an Ubuntu subsystem, but I've also logged in from the command prompt on Windows, and I had the same issue.

This is a visual problem (ie: the cursor's actual position remains the same) where the cursor appears at the right end of the terminal on the line. If I move the cursor up or down a line and then back to the original position, I can see it in the correct place again; however, once I move it forward more, the cursor jumps out of place again.

Is there a known fix for this?

Comment: So you run emacs in the Terminal, but in what OS? Have you tried connecting via different terminal software. Some systems—like macOS—sometimes have terminal emulation issues with rendering that only show up sporadically like this.

Comment: @JakeGould I'm in Windows 10 logging into a server via ssh. I typically work in an Ubuntu subsystem, but I've also logged in from the command prompt, and I had the same issue.

Comment: @underasail: neither Windows 10 nor SSH are terminal emulators.  Are you using PuTTY? A stab in the dark:  Emacs-23 is pretty old, so maybe the Ubuntu server is using an description of your terminal's capabilities (termcap/terminfo) that doesn't match the capabilities of your actual terminal because yours is "the same but much newer"?

Comment: @Stefan I'm using a linux subsystem (Ubuntu) in Windows 10. I've also used the Windows 10 command prompt to login via ssh.

Comment: I also have an install of emacs v26.1 on the server side where I see the same issue, so I'm not sure that conflict is causing it.